In flutter how to set the label location for DropdownMenu
As part of ThemeData I set the background color. Due to this the dropdown also get the same color I would like it to have same color as the textfield. However when I sent the color in the dropdown the lable is no longer at the top but overlaps with the default value of the dropdown.
How to do I make lable of the dropdown go to the top.
ThemeData
  theme: ThemeData(
    colorSchemeSeed: Colors.blueGrey,
    useMaterial3: true,
    appBarTheme: AppBarTheme(backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,),
    scaffoldBackgroundColor: const Color.fromARGB(255, 134, 173, 192),
    inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
     filled: true,
     fillColor: Colors.white,
    ),
   )


loadTypeDropdownMenu = DropdownMenu<String>(
  inputDecorationTheme: const InputDecorationTheme(
    fillColor: Colors.amber,
    filled: true,
    floatingLabelAlignment: FloatingLabelAlignment.center,
    floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always,
    floatingLabelStyle: TextStyle( 
    color: Colors.red, 
    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,         
    )
  ),
  initialSelection: defalutLoadType,
  label: const Text('Load Type'),
  dropdownMenuEntries: loadTypesEntries,
  onSelected: (String? loadType) {
    setState(() {
      selectedLoadType = loadType;
    });
  },
);



You want 1st image result?

Try below code
Default value
var selected = 'Load';

Dropdown Widget:
DropdownButtonFormField<String>(
      decoration: InputDecoration(
        border: OutlineInputBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
          borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey),
        ),
        labelText: 'Load Type',
        labelStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
      ),
      value: selected,
      items: ["Load", "Pressure", "Work", "Pending", "Completed"]
          .map(
            (label) => DropdownMenuItem(
              child: Text(label),
              value: label,
            ),
          )
          .toList(),
      onChanged: (value) {
        setState(() => selected = value!);
      },
    ),

Result:

Before Selection 

After Selection  



thanks after adding I am suddenly getting following error any ideia why?
CRITICAL **: 16:26:03.375: void update_pressing_state(FlKeyEmbedderResponder *, uint64_t, uint64_t): assertion 'lookup_hash_table(self->pressing_records, physical_key) != 0' failed

Can you add your full code snippet for more understand, or before try to clean and pub get the project

not sure what happned i just a git clone in another directory and it start it work.

but one question  When i have a default value for the dropdown at that time Load Type is behind the default value. only on selecting the dropdown does the "Load Type" goes to top right hand

@kumar Yes I agree, the reason is when dropdown is Active that time only labelText change it position. Flutter handles the transition between the label being displayed as a placeholder and being displayed above the dropdown when it's active. This is typically controlled by the floatingLabelBehavior
property of the InputDecoration widget.

I tried your suggestion floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always but no change

@kumar I have update my answer with default value please check, I am not using any behavior
